# В скрипте выдает ошибку Unknown Word

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, visual-studio-code, unity3d

Здраствуйте, у меня появилась проблема с компилятором VSCode. Вообщем когда запускаю скрипт из юнити, он работает, но в коде не показываются подсказки, хотя я все подключил правильно, и расширения для юнити тоже установлены. А еще выдает такую ошибку при открытии любого скрипта. Скрин ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collsion){
    if(collsion.CompareTag("Destroyer")){
     Destroy(gameObject);
    }else if(collsion.CompareTag("HeroDestr")){
       Destroy(gameObject);
    } 
   }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код "любого скрипта"

Comment: Прикрепил код выше

Comment: Это похоже не ошибка, а просто предупреждение спелл-чекера, его можно игнорировать.

Comment: Скажите почему у меня вылазит вместо подсказок вот это? Прикрепил выше

Comment: Подсказки вылазят плсле того как вы точку поставите

Comment: я вкурсе, но даже после точки ничего не появляется